# Mirror modifier active after applying

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

**Blender Version** 
2.79b (2.79b 2018-03-22, Blender Foundation)

**Issue:**
As per the screenshot the mirror modifier still appears to be active (see the crease I added) even though it is no longer seen under the "modifiers" section of this object.

I'm quite new to Blender.  Is this a bug or something I am doing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the Sculpt mode. Turn off Symmetry/Lock in the T-panel

[image]